# Why does the system tell me this on SSH login?

Tags: 20.04, hardware-enablement-stack

I'm just wondering why the system tells me this dialogue when I log in with SSH.

```
Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2025.
```

I may be wrong, but I think that I do not get security updates after this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's telling you that you have a Hardware Enablement (HWE) kernel, and that standard support for that kernel ends in 2025.

A typical LTS release of Ubuntu uses the same kernel version for it's entire five-year life, with only security patches and critical bugfixes. (Ubuntu 20.04 = kernel 5.**4**.x)

An HWE kernel bumps every six months to a whole new kernel version. Bumping ends after two years. (Ubuntu 20.04 with HWE = kernel 5.**15**.x)

For Ubuntu 20.04 users, 5.15.x is the end of the line. It's been two years. No new version bumps (22.04 is available for that). The current 5.15 kernel will keep getting security patches and critical bugfixes until 2025.

The reason it's telling you at every login is that folks sometimes forget. Especially over five years.